# __int128 additions/subtractions

Tags: c++, c

is there any other approach of using __int128 numbers but without classes? I implemented also a compressor/decompressor and want to test it with __int128 numbers. The main aim of these source files is to test the possibility to go below the Hutter Prize Limit of 15932968 of enwik8 file. Do you know about an inside error specific to __int128 type probably regarding an overflow due to cast conversions? It is hard to belive that the file 15932968 can be compressed again but I think __int128 approach is a new way not tested for the compression limit.

I posted this questions also on the following link and added there the c source files: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/forums/forum/723797/topic/6592960

Do you have any hints about how the additions/subtarctions, cast conversions should be done in order to avoid implausible data when performing these operations?

Comment: What leads you to think there are any problems with operations on `__int128`? The liked post does not seem to indicate anything not explained by the fact that you can't write `__int128` literals.

Comment: Oh, and please decide whether you want C or C++. Because in C++ the answer would probably involve things like custom literals and classes wrapping `__int128` to make sure you don't convert it to smaller size by accident and a lot more C++ stuff that simply does not exist in C.

Comment: Also please tag your post with the platform and compiler. This is neither C nor C++, but an extension that might be provided by some platforms.

Comment: In total your question could gain much by being more precise from the start. What "other approach" do you mean?